# Open a chrome newtab with url chrome://newtab/

Tags: javascript

The first line works fine, but the second one doesn't work; why?

```
// Works
window.open('https://google.com/', '_blank'); 

// Doesn't work, why?
window.open('chrome://newtab/', '_blank');
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to security issues, sadly, you cannot do this in chrome. The best you can do would be to point to [google.com](https://google.com) if you want the user to have a search bar or something like that. For example, something like this would work:

```html
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Search Anything</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, utilizing accessible browser APIs, you won't be able to perform what you desire. `window.open` has the following syntax: `window.open(URL, name, specs, replace)`. The first two specify how this new "window" will be opened. The address of the window's destination. These can be left blank, but it will open a window titled `about:blank`. The name specifies how the window should be opened, is the second portion (tab, window, etc.).

This URL can't load local resources; therefore, "chrome:/newtab" won't function. If you try to use a period in your URL, it will open a new window with the last website you visited. If you try to start a new window with a slash in the URL, it will open with the base path of the new window. I tested invalid URLs (random strings and characters), and they merely opened a new window with your current URL and appended anything you wrote.

**Sources for Reference**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: so is there any other way to open homepage? I set newtab url to homepage and thought opening a newpage will bring homepage but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can’t open new tab like we open in browser by clicking "+"  but you can open blank browser page by using `window.open("about:blank","_blank")`.
Because whenever we hit "+" icon in browser trigger event and append required thing like shortcut and all internally into the blank page only.

Answer (score 0):

You can just try this out:

```js
const newtab = () =>‌ window.open('dummy url', '_blank');
```

I think that would work for you ;)